# Can I have two external displays connected to my laptop?

Tags: video, display, external-display

I have a Dell XPS M1530, and I already have one external display connected.

I was wondering if I could have another one connected through the HDMI port.
I already tried plugging them both in and it just uses the one that I already had plugged in.

Is there a setting that I can change? Or would I have to buy a better video card or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can have up to two monitors going at the same time (including your laptop screen). If you connect two external monitors and enable them both, your laptop screen will turn off. This is due to the HDMI actually being a shared port. Being a laptop, I don't know how many options you have with adding a different graphics cards. Some laptops carry this capability, but most are integrated onto the main board (both integrated and discrete cards).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this type of product to add another display on a laptop or desktop PC. Prices are reasonable on the entry level units [Startech USB video](http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters)

Comment: I've used similar products. It was horrible. It acted like I was Remote Desktop'd into a machine over dialup. I returned it the same day. Great if you absolutely must have it, but horrible if you're trying to do much of anything productive. This was on a workstation and just had Outlook on that monitor. It was barely usable.

Comment: @kobaltz - These products are fine if and only if they're using a DisplayLink chipset.  (You still won't be watching real-time video on them though.)  Every imitator product I've tried has been HORRIBLE, but DisplayLink is good quality stuff.